# Book where man is abducted by crab-people aliens

Tags: story-identification

It's a sci fi I read in the early 90s about a man who gets abducted by aliens (crab-people) and is kept in a room where they watch him. They put him in with another alien species female that looks pretty much human. She ends up getting pregnant, has a baby, and the baby dies. He finds a way to escape by going through the floor. He takes crab person hostage and escapes back to Earth, I think. Then it starts to get fuzzy. Pretty sure it was a series. Paperback in early 90s but came from retirement home book sale.

Answer (score 15):

F. M. Busby's "Cage a Man", first book of the [Demu Trilogy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671432885)

> "Barton couldn't believe it, even while it was happening. One moment
> he was alive and well on Earth, then in a flash he found himself
> hurtling through millions of miles of uncharted space-- prisoner of an
> advanced alien race whose humanitarian plan involves the surgical
> transformation on all mankind into misshapen parodies of themselves."

Escaping the cage:

> ...he curled up in the middle of the floor, well away from the
> latrine and feeding areas, and began willing himself as
> close to death as he might possibly get back from, and
> perhaps a little further. Besides hallucination and self-hypnosis
> and faking, he threw in considerably more true
> death wish than he would have done if he were still capable
> of giving a real damn. He knew what he was doing, but
> it didn't frighten him. The floor would not allow passage
> of a living organism; therefore Barton had to be effectively
> dead. That was how he had figured it, what he was
> betting on. There was no other chance for Barton, none
> at all.

> The sensation of interpenetrating the floor was disturbing
> beyond anything he could have imagined; he
> hadn't expected to be able to feel anything. But his will
> held; he gave no betraying heartbeat. Some ghost at the
> back of his mind tried to guess how many pounds of his
> own excrement he was finally following, but the estimate
> was impossible. He didn't know how many years it had
> been, let alone his average excretion.

> The sudden drop through the air and subsequent impact
> jarred him. He saw through slit-tight eyelids that he
> was on the floor of a corridor. At least he had lucked out
> and missed the plumbing. Only one robed lobster was in
> sight. It approached, bent over him and reached ...

[image]

Comment: Definitely correct.  See also here, for another possible instance of this book:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261321/1980s-sci-fi-novel-with-multiple-races-involved-in-an-interstellar-war/261326#261326